# Custom navigation menu in Liferay?

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am using Liferay 6 with Tomcat 7 and Liferay SDK for java to develop a custom website which will be handled by one portlet. The thing is that i dont really like the navigation bar in Liferay and I want to redesign it with custom CSS navigation menu. I tried to find the CSS files but for some reason I have 2 CSS files named custom.css(one in the root folder of the theme the other one in some sub-folder). Which one I have to work on? And how I can change the .vm file in such way that is going to suit my CSS.

I want to make a boxed navigation menu with five links and each of them to be separated(typical CSS navigation menu).

Any advice or help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to customize the navigation bar in liferay with some boxed navigation, i suggest you to look into navigation.vm file under your theme.And modify the css accordingly used for the navigation bar.